# SQL WHERE and LIKE clause duplicated

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Hi guys I'm new to SQL and trying to learn it by myself.
I have the following questions when I did the tutorial questions in sqlzoo website. Assume I have a table which contains info for all countries in the world.

When I want to query the country which its name containing 'A' and 'B' , I use the following query

```
SELECT name 
FROM world
WHERE name LIKE '%A%'
AND name LIKE '%B%'
```

here I can repeated use the `name LIKE` query

However, when I want to query the country which its name is Vietnam and Thailand, I can only use the query

```
SELECT name
FROM world 
WHERE name IN ('Thailand', 'Vietnam')
```

instead of

```
WHERE name = 'Thailand'
AND name = 'Vietnam'
```

Can somebody kindly explain the reason behind this? When I can use many `AND xxxx` and when I cannot use that.

Thanks so much !

Comment: You should use `WHERE name = 'Thailand'
OR name = 'Vietnam'`. Study the difference between `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: Exactly as @Renzo mentions. It wouldn't make sense to check for the name to be both `Thailand` and `Vietnam`. It simply doesn't make sense, but the `OR` is exactly for these purposes.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE name = 'Thailand'
AND name = 'Vietnam'
```

This one searches for the country which has both 'Thailand' and 'Vietnam' in its name. but

```
SELECT name
FROM world 
WHERE name IN ('Thailand', 'Vietnam')
```

This one searches Countries which names are either 'Thailand' OR 'Vietnam'

That is the deference between them.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE name = 'Thailand' AND name = 'Vietnam'
```

AND is a boolean AND and return the result where the country name = Thailand and name = Vietnam in a single row.

Instead use

```
WHERE name = 'Thailand' OR name = 'Vietnam'
```

Answer (score 2):

And returns to you the results which obey ALL the rules you have stated.

Can a country name be 'Thailand' AND the SAME country name be 'Vietnam', 
at the same time? i hope you see that the answer to this is no.
So this is a classic example where you need to use 'OR' instead of 'AND',
Why? because then you will get a result back where the name = 'Thailand' and also the result where the name = 'Vietnam', because both of them obey the 'OR' rule, meaning both names are Either 'Vietnam' or 'Thailand'.

The reason this wrong way of using AND instead of OR is working for you in the first case you mentioned is because you are using wildcards. and there are country names where you can have an 'A' and a 'B' at the SAME TIME in different places inside the SAME country name.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE name IN ('Thailand', 'Vietnam')
```

Is the same as

```
WHERE name = 'Thailand'
OR name = 'Vietnam'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check condition to match any one element from the given list of element then you should use.

```
WHERE name IN ('Thailand', 'Vietnam')
```

and if you want to satisfy both condition then you should use below code

```
WHERE name = 'Thailand'
AND name = 'Vietnam'
```

Note :- result of AND condition should always false
because name can be either 'Thailand' or 'Vietnam'

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` conditions are always applied **per record**. So

```
WHERE name = 'Thailand'
AND name = 'Vietnam'
```

does not mean: find all records in the table for the names 'Thailand' and 'Vietnam'.

It means: Find records that have a name that equals both 'Thailand' and 'Vietnam'. But a name can only be either 'Thailand' or 'Vietnam' or none of them, never both at the same time of course.

So use `OR` instead in order to find records where the name either equals 'Thailand' **or** 'Vietnam':

```
WHERE name = 'Thailand'
OR name = 'Vietnam'
```

And as you already know you can look up the list of countries instead with `IN` which makes it more readable

```
WHERE name IN ('Thailand', 'Vietnam')
```

and less prone to errors. A typical mistake:

```
WHERE name = 'Thailand' OR name = 'Vietnam'
AND size = 'big'
```

which translates to

```
WHERE name = 'Thailand' 
OR (name = 'Vietnam' AND size = 'big')
```

rather than

```
WHERE (name = 'Thailand' OR name = 'Vietnam')
AND size = 'big'
```

because `AND` has precedence over `OR`. So when using both `AND` and `OR` use parentheses. And as mentioned use `IN` instead of `OR` when possible.